# Notification does not work for ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have a class with 2 properties of ObservableCollection :

```
Public ObservableCollection<User> Users
     { get {return this._users;}}

Public ObservableCollection<User> Admins
     { get {return new ObservableCollection<User>(Users.Where(u => u.type == 1));}}
```

the issue is when I change a user, the property Users is notified and not Admins.
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

If you bind to Admins in your view, it will get a copy of a new ObservableCollection of users.

If you then code Admins.Add(new User()) in your viewmodel, it will be operating on a different instance than what was bound.

You should change your code so it uses a single instance (and not recreate it every time).

**Edit (added example):**

```
    private ObservableCollection<User> _admins = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    public ObservableCollection<User> Admins
    {
         get
         {
             _admins.Clear();
             Users.ForEach(p => { if (p.type == 1) { _admins.Add(p); } });
             return _admins;
         }
    }
```

Note that the *instance* of the ObservableCollection does not change (this is the key to the solution).  I simply clear it and reload the users into the collection.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I'm binding the Admins property to a DataGridColumn, do you have any suggestion to change the code ?

Comment: @DotNeter The easiest way to fix it is to add a `CollectionChanged` event to `Users` that raises the `PropertyChanged` event for `"Admins"` so it gets re-evaluated anytime the Users collection changes. For example, `Users.CollectionChanged += Users_CollectionChanged`, where `Users_CollectionChanged` calls `RaisePropertyChanged("Admins");`

Comment: @DotNeter updated my answer to include a solution.  Rachel's solution works too, but requires hooking up an event handler.  I'll leave it to you to decide which approach you prefer.  I prefer not to create a new instance of a collection every time the getter is called, as you will then have additional garbage collection and references floating around.

Comment: Thanks alot for both of you, Rachel's solution works fine, but the solution of Bahri does not work, ObservableCollection does not contain a method called ForEach, thanks again :)

Comment: @DotNeter add "using System.Linq;" to your includes.